# Select/Get html node from an element using D3

Tags: select, d3.js

Let's say I have an html object called `element` that I create using bellow code:

```
var xmlString = "<div class="parent"><span class="child"></span></div>"
parser = new DOMParser()
var element = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

// or simply using jquery
var string = "<div class="parent"><span class="child"></span></div>"
var element = $(string);
```

What I want to do is to select `span.child` from `element` using `D3`, not from the document. Using `d3.select('span.child')` will try to look for the `<span class="child"></span>` in the html document.

I checked the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) and it says:

> A selection is an array of elements pulled from the current document.

But I want to select not from the document but from the above `element` that I just created. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of debugging I found out that if `element` is a object, not string, then `d3.select(element)` will not look for the `element` in the document instead it will return the `element` itself.

for detailed info:

```
  d3.select = function(node) {
    var group = [ typeof node === "string" ? d3_select(node, d3_document) : node ];
    group.parentNode = d3_documentElement;
    return d3_selection([ group ]);
  };
```